# Android toast text when I click button on type in edit text

Tags: android, xml

I want to be able to make [Toast Text](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) when I click button on type in edit text.

My code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText input;
private Button click;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(appContext, "My Msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Comment: try to search and read document than Ask question

Comment: next time please try searching first before posting such questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private EditText input;

private Button click;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.getText().toString, 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.getText().toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, input.getText().toString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

simple :)